# draw.io text wrapping. Is it possible to clip the text?

Tags: draw.io

I have a text area in draw.io
Some lines of text are very long. I want them to be clipped and not go outside the text area. (Don't want any text to go to a new line. Only want to clip long lines).

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you select it, click Text overflow under Property/Value on the right and test if Hidden, Width or Fill options help.